# jQuery - loading content into DIV, links not working in Safari

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with jQuery and Safari (5.03).  Hope this makes sense.

I am using the code below to load a page into a DIV.  On the parent page I have some code that selects all links in the content that is loaded and tells this to the links (when clicked) into the same DIV.  This works fine in IE, Firefox, and Chrome, but I cannot get it to work in Safari.  resultsDisplay is the class of all the links in in the content that is loaded.  Does this make any sense?  How can I can the links in the loaded content to load into that same div on the parent page (#results).

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$(".resultsDisplay a").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
   url: $(this).attr("href"),
   success: function(msg){
     $("#results").html(msg);
   }
 });
 return false;
});
});
```

Here is the page I referring to:

http://www.fishur.com

The content reloads as a new page in the browser rather than inside the DIV.  Click on one of this fish names is IE/FireFox/Safari and you'll see what I mean - then click one of the names in Safari.

Comment: what does it load? does it load anything at all? can you post an example page?

Comment: Ok, the question has been updated.  Thanks!

Comment: It also fails on chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE

I see the real problem here.  You are loading those elements dynamically, while you are only setting the event handlers at document onload.  The elements don't exist when this code is executed.  To solve this problem use jQuery's `live()` handlers or re-run the init after the load of that section.

---

Don't put the url in the href element.  Instead use something else.  The browser is opening the href when the url is clicked.

Another option:  Don't use an `<a>` tag for these buttons.

Another option:  Use the jQuery event.preventDefault();

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, could you show me an example?  Thanks!

Comment: Which item do you want an example for?

Comment: Hmm..  I tried the preventDefault method and it didn't seem to change.  I guess I'm not sure how I would remove the href element.  The browser needs that to know which page/parameters to load doesn't it?

Comment: Maybe I should also mention, I'm using the same code for the terms of service / privacy policy and it's working fine.  That content is on the parent page - not sure why content being loaded into the DIV is different in Safari

Comment: Yes, I copied David's code below.  It's still seeing the link as a traditional <a href>.

Comment: Ugh, frustrating.  I changed it to use the .live handler and it's still not working in safari.  $(".resultsDisplay a").live("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

Comment: Hey!  I got it to work!  I was changing the code in the content DIV rather than the parent page.  Looks all good now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$(".resultsDisplay a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        success: function(msg){
            $("#results").html(msg);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

You have to prevent the default action.